# php - Parse error

Tags: php

I have written some code and it doesn't seem to be working. I can't seem to see why it's not:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password)
(
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","1001","Larissa") or die("Couldn't connect")
    mysql_select_db("login");
        or die ("Couldnt find db");

)

else

die("Please enter a username and a password");

?>
```

The error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in H:\xampp1htdocs\1001\test_login.php on line 10

Comment: "Find my syntax error" is indeed a case of "too localized" question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
( // this should be {

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","1001","Larissa") or die("Couldn't connect") // insert ; here
mysql_select_db("login"); // remove ;
or die ("Couldnt find db");

) // this should be }

else

die("Please enter a username and a password");

?>
```

also:

1. using `or die()` is a (very) bad programming style. Mostly because users are presented error messages they won't understand
2. check if request values are set before using them
3. learn to indent your code properly
4. spaces can make code more readable
5. don't use [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) if you don't want to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) at least consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semicolon on line 8 and have an improper one on line 9

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","1001","Larissa") or die("Couldn't connect") // <-- add one here
mysql_select_db("login"); // <-- remove this one
or die ("Couldnt find db");
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a semi-colon after `mysql_select_db("login")` in line 8.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon at the end of this line...

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","1001","Larissa") or die("Couldn't connect")
```

Also, as a future "for reference", whenever PHP gives you an error that sounds like **unexpected XXX in YYY on line ZZ**, It's usually the line **before** the one the error says.

Comment: when i put the semicolon at the end of that line- line 9, it comes up with an error... parse error, syntax error unexpected ';' in .... on line 9

Comment: As pointed out in other answers, you have **multiple** errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `connect`line is missing a semicolon *after* `die()`, and your `mysql_select_db()` line has an extraneous semicolon *before* `die()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors.

You forgot a semicolon on the `mysql_connect` line. When PHP then finds "mysql_select_db" in a place where it doesn't make sense for a function call to be, it assumes it's an unquoted string and tries processing that instead. Obviously it can't, so unexpected `T_STRING` is thrown.

The other error is that you put a semicolon after the `select_db` call, but before the `or die`. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password)
{ //fix number 1 - instead of "("

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","1001","Larissa") or die("Couldn't connect"); //fix number 2 (added ;)
    mysql_select_db("login")or die ("Couldnt find db"); //fix number 3

} //fix number 4 - instead of "("

else
 die("Please enter a username and a password");

?>
```